# How to transalte messages that comes from server in react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, internationalization

I'm building a react-native app with spanish as default language, the problem is that I'm using a open source backend service to serve data and this data comes is in english by default. What I want is to **transalate this data/messages that comes from server in my react-native app to show to the user the messages in spanish not in english.**

This is the first time I am doing this process and it is not clear to me what are the steps or the flow that is generally followed for this kind of proces(translate messages that comes from server in my app).

Answer (score 0):

You have many approaches to such a thing one comes to mind is

1. Catch the error/api response message which mostly server error messages comes in codes and messages.
2. set a condition statement if code equal 2 that means the server is down for example

**Example:**
You made a request to the server and there was an error with the server let say wrong username and password, now the server returns a message and a error code you have to get the code or the message and show your own message

```
.....made the request the server returned 
{ code: 192, message: Wrong username/Password }

now in your code you will do the following 

if(code == 192){
  ...do your message
}
```

P.S this is just on top my head since you didn't share any codes or responses from your server.

UPDATE :

If you want to translate all your strings/messages that comes from the server you would need to do another approche something like this

1. Create a file contain all the strings/codes from the server
2. compare messages/code comes from the server and the file will return the text you want

   `{ "102": "Hola", "103": "Bien", "104": "Nada", "105": "Si", }`

now this file contain the error/message code all you have to do is when you receive the code grab the message from this file

```
let translation = {
  "101": "Hola",
  "102":"Si"
};
translation["102"]; // Result will be Si
```

Now this is the most accurate approach but you have to know all the messages/codes comes from the server, now if you want something to translate on the fly you might wanna use translation library and may not be accurate translation

Comment: I'm talking more about an internationalization process, remember that it is not only error messages that come from the server also other types of strings or messages, according to your approach I would have to check each message that comes from the server and confront it with some condition to verify the type of message and thus translate it ... is what I can understand from your answer.

Comment: My answer was based on your question "Messages refer to API Responses as errors or other backend string/messages."

Comment: ok, let me explain a bit better, what I want is to translate any message that comes from the server, because as I mentioned in the question, all the strings that the server returns are in english and what I want is to show those messages to the user in spanish.

Comment: so based on that, you need to know what's the messages that comes from your server, otherwise you need to use translation service which not recommended because you have to send the translation to server to translate it like Google Translation and wait for the response

Comment: Is there any way to do this process with an internationalisation library like `react-intl` or something like that? As I mentioned before, I am not very clear about the internationalisation process and if this kind of libraries could help me to solve the problem of translations in the app.

Comment: That library is based on the approach i mentioned earlier which creating translation file and pull from there, there is no library will automatically translate words for you but if you looking to do multi language app you need to look into `i18n-js` and `react-native-localize`.